# Restsharp, responce as chunked with diffent JSON documents

Tags: dynamic, restsharp, json-deserialization, chunked

Hello I have made a request to a http server as an event service. This server sends events as chunked data. Because there are diffrent events, I got diffrent JSON documents. 
Question 1. How to read this data everytime I get a new pice of data, not only if the connection is closed?
Question 2. How to parse the JSON in different Objects, depending on the event and have this as a return type?

The http stream looks like:

```
GET /OTEvents?subscriptionId=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTUyNzY2MTg0MX0.fxsP4bLNzqSSFtYsTNmyyV4bM-OBwhcwhy-w_HwQYmQ HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com:8014
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,de;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed May 30 08:31:22 CEST 2018
Server: donoa
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

3d
{"eventName":"OnChannelInformation","text":"Chunk started"}

262
{"eventName":"OnCallCreated","loginName":"oxe11","callRef":"1b460e5b1f3c0100","callData":{"initialCalled":{"id":{"phoneNumber":"11"}},"state":"RINGING_INCOMING","tags":[],"capabilities":{"addMedias":[],"redirect":true,"pickedUp":true,"redirectToVoiceMail":true,"terminate":true}},"legs":[{"deviceId":"11","media":"AUDIO","state":"RINGING_INCOMING","capabilities":{"answer":true}}],"participants":[{"participantId":"198","identity":{"id":{"phoneNumber":"198"},"firstName":"Raum 2.1","lastName":"Hotline","type":{"main":"EXTERNAL","subType":"pbx"}},"medias":[],"mediaCapabilities":[]}],"deviceCapabilities":[]}

148
{"eventName":"OnCallModified","loginName":"oxe11","callRef":"1b460e5b1f3c0100","modifiedLegs":[],"addedLegs":[{"deviceId":"99999851","media":"AUDIO","state":"RINGING_INCOMING","capabilities":{"answer":true}}],"removedLegs":[],"modifiedParticipants":[],"addedParticipants":[],"removedParticipantIds":[],"deviceCapabilities":[]}
```

---

The chunk data is received asynchronously. I'd like to generate from every chunk an "event" object and call back my main function.

Comment: You'll have more success attracting a useful solution if you do a better job of showing what you've tried.  Try something out, post some code and any error message you might get.

Comment: I have update my question with the http data to provide more info on my problem

Comment: Excellent start. I've formatted your code for you. If you think of anything else that might attract an answer (hint: more detailed information), you should definitely edit your question and add it in.